# Having to reason

Tags: grammar

What does "having to reason" mean here? Are "exhausting" and "having" gerund here? Can I use "having" instead of "having to"? Is it following this structure? "It's +adj+v+ing something"

> Of course it's exhausting, **having to reason** all the time in a universe which wasn't meant to be reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are "exhausting" and "having" gerund here?

*Exhausting* is being used as an adjective, with the meaning "extremely tiring".

*Having to* is an auxiliary, meaning, "being required to" or "needing to".

There's a sort of play on words being used where *reason* means "to think critically" or "to apply logic", and the second *reasonable* means "sensible" or "logical".